# C linux sem_wait doesn't work (sometimes) in threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, semaphore

I paste only model, which shows the problem. In function: 
`int get_random_prime(mpz_t number)` I've got: `sem_wait(&prime_count);` and it doesn't work properrly.It waits and waits and waits even if semaphore is greater that 0.

```
#include<gmp.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

size_t number_of_cores=2;   
pthread_mutex_t mutex_queue;    
sem_t prime_count;              
sem_t threads_count;                    
size_t last_length=0;           
size_t prime_got=0;             
char manager_on=0;              

mpz_t prime;


get_random_odd(mpz_t output,size_t length){

    size_t i;
    size_t dev_random;
    int randomFile= open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);

    read(randomFile,&dev_random,8);
    mpz_set_ui(output,dev_random);

    for(i=1;i<(length/64);i++){
        read(randomFile,&dev_random,8);
        mpz_mul_2exp (output,output, 64);
        mpz_add_ui(output,output,dev_random);
    }

    close(randomFile);

    mpz_setbit(output,length-1);
    mpz_setbit(output,0);
}

void* get_random_prime_thread(void* ptr_length){
    size_t result = 0;
    size_t i;
    size_t length = *((size_t*)ptr_length);
    mpz_t number;
    mpz_init(number);

    //do{
        get_random_odd(number, length);
        i=0;
    /*  do{
            result=miller_rabin_test(number);
            i++;
        }while(result==1 && i<prime_precision);*/
    //}while(result==0);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_queue);
    mpz_set(prime,number);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_queue);

    sem_post(&prime_count);
    mpz_clear(number);  
    pthread_exit(NULL);

};

void* get_random_prime_manager_start(void* length){
    size_t i;
    size_t size=32;
    pthread_t *threads=malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*size);
    manager_on =1;

    pthread_t rc;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_queue,NULL);
    sem_init(&threads_count,0,number_of_cores);
    sem_init(&prime_count,0,0);

    i=-1;

    do{
        sem_wait(&threads_count);
        i++;
                printf("PROCES:%d\n",i);
        if(i>=size){
            threads=realloc(threads,size*2);
        }
        rc=pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,get_random_prime_thread,length);
        if(rc){
            printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
            pthread_exit((void*)-1);
        }
    }while(manager_on);

    for(i;i>0;i--){
        pthread_cancel(threads[i]);
    }

    free(threads);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_queue);
    sem_destroy(&threads_count);
    sem_destroy(&prime_count);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void* get_random_prime_manager_stop(){
    manager_on=0;
}

int get_random_prime(mpz_t number){

    sem_wait(&prime_count);
    printf("GET\n");
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_queue);
    mpz_set(number,prime);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_queue);
    sem_post(&threads_count);
    return 0;
};

int main(){
    mpz_init(prime);
    size_t rc;
    size_t length=1024;
    pthread_t thread;
    mpz_t p,q,n;
    mpz_init(p);
    mpz_init(q);
    mpz_init(n);

    size_t half_length=length/2;
    rc=pthread_create(&thread,NULL,get_random_prime_manager_start,(void*)&half_length); 
    if(rc){
        printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    do{
        get_random_prime(p);
        get_random_prime(q);

        mpz_mul(n,p,q);
    }while( mpz_sizeinbase(n,2)==length);

    get_random_prime_manager_stop();

    mpz_clear(p);
    mpz_clear(q);
    mpz_clear(n);
}
```

Is it possible that thread wait on semaphore that hasn't been initiated yet?

Comment: you missed `size*=2;` after `threads=realloc(threads,size*2);`.

Comment: @mch thx, you right, but it don't solve the problem, becouse if it hangs it hangs just after first 2 threads

Comment: you should create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the `sem_init` calls complete before you try to use any of the semaphores. The best way to do this is to call `get_random_prime_manager_start` normally and let it initialize the semaphores, start a thread, and then return. That way, you are assured that the manager is sufficiently started for it to be safe to use it when the function returns.

Comment: variable `manager_on` is changing to 0 after calling `get_random_prime`

Comment: maybe I don't understand what do you mean, but I destroy semaphore after calling `get_random_prime` I put one more function to my question to explain this.

Comment: Is it possible I try wait on semaphore that hasn't been initiated yet? Becouse its faster wait that initiate sometimes?